# Nested transactions are not allowed. Use commitTransaction() after each beginTransaction().

Tags: android, realm

This is the code for my project and i'm using Realm as my DB.

I've gone through similar question as mine but could not fix it, so posted it here.
Here's what i have gone through https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/542

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);



        if (HttpError.checkStatusSuccessForResponse(statusCode, result))
        {
            Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationController.getInstance());
            realm.beginTransaction();

        try {

            JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResult.getJSONArray("phone_numbers");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {

                //                  List<R_LocalContactDB> localContactDb = Select
                //                          .from(R_LocalContactDB.class)
                //                          .where(Condition.prop("PHONE").eq(jsonArray.get(i)))
                //                          .list();

                RealmResults<R_LocalContactDB> localContact = realm.where(R_LocalContactDB.class).equalTo("phone",jsonArray.get(i).toString()).findAll();

                if (localContact.size() > 0)
                {

                    R_LocalContactDB localDb = localContact.get(0);
                    localDb.setStatus(1);
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(localDb);
                    realm.commitTransaction();

                }
            }

            localContactsSyncCallBack.didFinishProfileSync(true, null);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Server Response ", "Exception " + result);
        }


    }
    else {

        Log.d("Server Response ",
                "Exception "
                        + HttpError
                                .parseErrorFromServer(statusCode, result));

    }

}
```

I keep getting the Nesting error! Can someone help.

Comment: what is expected in super.onPostExecute(result);?I double whether it required....

Comment: i'm just overriding the method, but i want to get the local contact with the Realm query

Comment: You should use `executeTransaction()` instead of `realm.beginTransaction()` and `realm.commitTransaction()`

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the transaction inside a loop/if block. Either you risk never closing the transaction or calling commit too many times. Also if an exception is thrown you also keep the transaction open. You can see how we handle this situation here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/src/main/java/io/realm/Realm.java#L989-Lundefined